# Check split tunnel

Tags: vpn, split-tunneling

I am using Shrew Client 2.2.2 to use a VPN connection with split tunneling. How can I check or where can I see, that the split tunnel is working properly?

Thanks in advance,
Dirk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traceroute will show you the path your traffic is following. With split tunneling, a traceroute to an internet IP should not pass your VPN gateway.

Another way to make sure traffic to the internet is not going through the tunnel is by visiting a website which shows your IP address (eg. [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) or [ifconfig.me](http://ifconfig.me)). If your IP address is from your local provider and not from the network your tunnel is connected to, the packets were routed to the website directly, not through the tunnel.

Comment: I used pathping to check the route. In all of them I found directly after my computer the VPN host. Do I have no split tunnel, or is it because of the enabled DNS and WINS (both obtained automatically)? Nevertheless, is it possible to have a split tunnel with a fixed DNS and WINS server? If yes, how can I check this?

Comment: In addition: The check on whatsmyip.com shows me the IP of my local provider. Can I assume from this, that the split tunnel works?

Comment: If your public IP is that of your local connection, and not the VPN endpoint, that suggests split tunneling is working.

Answer (score 0):

Generally split tunnel enable us to access internet host application or resources from Laptops connected with split tunnel configured vpn at the same time even we can  access organization intranet application as well ..

To verify this connectivity whether split tunnel is working or not

Tracert any internet hosted application from laptop it should use your internet service provide(ISP) gateway to reach destination

Tracert any intranet hosted application that is organisation local hosted website it should take gateway ip of your organization public ip which is used to connect vpn .